# doxygen a variable is recognized as function

Tags: c, doxygen, 8051, sdcc

In my current project I'm trying to generate documentation with doxygen. However I have a problem with a variable. Somehow doxygen recognizes the variable as a function.

The code:

```
__xdata __at (0x0F00) volatile static unsigned char Programmed; /*!< an indicator if     the board is programmed or not, during init copied from flash to xram*/

/*! 
*   The main loop that does all the magic
*   besides the "compiler startup" _sdcc_external_startup (in HWInit.c) is called to handle some "urgent" init (disabling of the watchdog)
*/
void main(void){
    unsigned short int TempUSInt;
    //init the device.
    Init_Device();
```

Note about the code: the code is written for the [SDCC compiler](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) for a 8051 microcontroller.
The `__xdata __at ()` directive is a special instruction so the compiler knows that it has to place the data in a separate memory segment (called XDATA) at a predetermined location (address 0x0F00).

My probem is that doxygen recognizes the `__at()` as a function instead of a variable and thus overwrites the `main()` function.

Although there are ways to make doxygen ignore the `__xdata __at () char Programmed` statement this has as downside that the variable is ignored and thus not documented.

So is there anyone who knows how to get doxygen to recognize the `__xdata __at () char Programmed` as a variable instead of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy would be to hide (define as empty) the compiler magic from doxygen with doxygen macros (untested; play around):

```
PREDEFINED = __xdata= \
             __at()=
```

You might also look at the docs for `EXPAND_AS_DEFINED`.

PS: Does your OS actually allow a `void`-returning main? If not, you should use `int main(void)`.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for the quick answer.
I need to mention that it also requires the settings `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES`
`MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES`
`EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES`
the rest can be default

Comment: About the return of main(): I'm on a microcontroller with no OS. So if my main exits I have a big problem ;-). My main is essentially `void main(void){ while(1){} }`. This is total normal on microcontrollers.

Comment: +1 Neat approach; but it does force those other settings which may not be ideal in the general case. An alternative would be to surround just the `__xdata __at (0x0F00) ` preamble with `\cond` ... `\endcond` comments assuming the compiler is happy with breaking the xdata line.

Comment: @Cheeseminer It looks like your approach also works. Although I did keep a single line for the case: `/*!\cond XDATAIGNORE*/__xdata __at (0x0F00) /*!\endcond*/ volatile static unsigned char Programmed; /*!< ...*/`. The downside of this method is that the code has a messier "feel" to it. So I will be using the method by @Jens but this also works.